# Suppress just a single blank page while using twosided in scrbook class

Tags: scrbook, blank-page

I think the title says all. How can I remove the blank page before a single chapter using the twosided parameter in the scrbook class? I want to keep all the other blank pages in the document, just suppress a single one.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\title{Test document}
\author{This is the title page.}
\date{January 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
%this is the only blank page that shall be suppressed
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]
%the blank page here shall be kept including the blank pages for all the upcoming chapters
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** With option `twoside` (default for class `scrbook`) a new chapter starts on a right page, that means a page with an odd page number. The margins (and maybe the content of the page header) depend on whether the page number is even (left page) or odd (right page). Removing the  blank page between the title page and the first chapter page changes the page number of the first chapter from odd (right page) to even (left page).

Should all chapters start on a left page (even page numbers)? Then use option `open=left` next to `\maketitle`

```latex
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Test document}
\author{This is the title page.}
\date{January 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\KOMAoptions{open=left}% <- added
%this is the only blank page that shall be suppressed
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]
%the blank page here shall be kept including the blank pages for all the upcoming chapters
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or should only the first chapter start on a left page (even page number)? Then use option `open=any` before the first chapter and reset the default by option `open=right`.

```latex
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Test document}
\author{This is the title page.}
\date{January 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
%this is the only blank page that shall be suppressed
\KOMAoptions{open=any}%<- added
\chapter{Chapter}
\KOMAoptions{open=right}%<- added
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-6]
%the blank page here shall be kept including the blank pages for all the upcoming chapters
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or should the title page to be a left page (even page number)? Then you can use `\maketitle[0]`, ie. the title page gets page number `0`.

```latex
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, twoside]{scrbook}
%\KOMAoptions{titlepage=firstiscover}% <- maybe you want to use this option
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Test document}
\author{This is the title page.}
\date{January 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle[0]% <- changed
%this is the only blank page that shall be suppressed
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]
%the blank page here shall be kept including the blank pages for all the upcoming chapters
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

with option `titlepage=firstiscover`

[image]

Comment: I didn't even think about the problems that would come up with the headers if I suppress one blank page. I will see how I'm going to handle it once I finished writing my thesis. However, the options you provided were exactly what I'm looking for.
Thanks a lot!